# Biometric Enrollment

Tags: login, pam, fingerprint-reader

I am interested in developing a Match-on-card Logon functionality (biometric enrollment) for users on Ubuntu. I've searched through PAM modules, in Ubuntu Software Center, and with Google, and found nothing that would help me.

The scenario is next: a smart card reader with fingerprint scanner is connected to the computer. User's fingerprint is stored on the smart card, not on the computer. So, when user inserts his card into the card reader, he also scans his fingerprint. Reader is supposed to compare the given fingerprint with the fingerprint on the card. If they match, user then has to enter his PIN on Ubuntu Login screen.

Is there a PAM module that does this, or do I have to write my own module? Also, where to start with writing PAM module, if that is necessary? Or, is there some other module, or library that make this functionality possible?

I have also bumped into BioAPI, but there is no explanation, or docs that I have found, that explains how to implement MoC on Ubuntu using PAM.